# What is the alternative for Multiple Inheritance in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to achieve Multiple Inheritance in C#. Or Any alternative way to achive Multiple Inheritance.  Can anyone help me ? Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Interfaces are a nice alternative. Essentially, an interface specifies what methods and properties must be implemented in a class that implements the interface. Sorry if that was confusing. Look here for more: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87d83y5b.aspx

Essentially, an interface would say that any class that uses this interface must implement `Foo()` and `Bar()`, but the interface would have no implementation. Rather it would be the responsibility of the class that uses the interface to implement those methods.

Interfaces can be a great tool depending on what you are looking for.

Comment: Any other alternative

Comment: what are you looking for       You could do what is called a composite (or whatever they are called) essentially just a variable of one class type within another class